# List of PHP Extensions & Modules

Tags: php, shell, command-line, command

I just moved my website from one server to another.

Is there any way through command line to get a list of all the PHP Extensions, Perl Modules, Apache Modules, and anything else above the user level that I may need to take with me from one server to the next?

I would think that there's a command that can be run to output lists like that, but just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
php -m
```

to list compiled-in modules from the command line

```
 --ri <name>
```

to show extended configuration information for the module specified by `<name>`

Perl, Apache etc all have their own equivalents

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see full information of your php configurations, you can use:

```
 phpinfo ();
```

Also, you can use some parameteres to see Extensions or modules. Find more in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php